# time.sleep() function is apparently a cause of invalid syntax

Tags: python, time, syntax

This is meant to be a program for a ticket vendor in Python.
It was working fine until I added in the `time.sleep` functions.
Here is my code:

```
    import time
    spaces = 61
    def init():
        global spaces
        if spaces > 1:
            print("Welcome to OCR's car park!")
            print("The number of spaces remaining is "+ str(spaces-1) +".")
            print("What are the last three letters on your number plate?")
            numplate = input()
            if len(numplate) != 3:
                print("These letters are invalid.")
                time.sleep(1)
                init()
            elif numplate.isalpha():
                print("It's £3.45 for a ticket. Enter how much money you want to insert. Type 'cancel' to cancel.")
        confirm = input()
        if confirm == "cancel":
            print("Payment cancelled.")
            time.sleep(3)
            init()
        if int(confirm) < 345:
            print("You don't have enough money.")
            time.sleep(1)
            init()
            print("£" +str(confirm)+ " inserted.")
            time.sleep(2)
        if float(confirm)> 345:
            print("Taking change...")
            time.sleep(3)
            confirm = float(confirm)-345
            print("Change due: £" +str(len(confirm[0]))+ "." +str(len(confirm[1]))+str(len(confirm[2]))     
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Printing ticket. Please wait.")
        time.sleep(5)
        print("Thank you for choosing OCR's car park!")
        spaces -= 1
        print("")
        print("")
        print("|-----|")
        print("| "+str(numplate.upper())+"|")
        print("|-----|")
        print("")
        print("")
        init()
    else:
        print("These letters are invalid.")
        time.sleep(1)
        init()
elif spaces < 2:
    print("No More Spaces.")
    init()
```

Every time I run it, it displays a pop-up saying `'invalid syntax'` and it always points to the `time.sleep(1)` function.

Comment: The error is on the line above. You have an unclosed bracket on the print line above. It is complaining about the sleep line as this line is being interpreted as a continuation of the line above. I'd suggest you try out an IDE like PyCharm or Eclipse which would highlight these errors for you.

Comment: In order to get help you should fix indentation first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in following line of yours.

```
print("Change due:£"str(len(confirm[0]))+"."+str(len(confirm[1]))+str(len(confirm[2]))
```

there's a closing parenthesis missing. Just add one more closing parenthesis.